# Significance testing of binary selection

Tags: statistical-significance

In an experiment, I am asking people to choose between two items (A or B). The task instructions use two different sentences (e.g., "pick A or B", "pick B or A", Q1 and Q2). In the results, it seems that the user behaviour is different with Q1 and Q2 (for example with N = 20):

```
_    A    B
Q1   8   12
Q2   13   7
```

Meaning that for a pair of items A and B, 8 people chose A with Q1, and B with Q2.

How do I test the statistical significance of these differences over a set of item pairs? Essentially I want to assess whether these are just random variations and to what extent Q1/Q2 have an effect on the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a typical use case for Fisher's test. It is a test of the odds ratio and whether that you can reject the null hypothesis $H_0$ that the true odds ratio is 1.

How it is done: http://www.quantpsy.org/fisher/fisher.htm

Using free software R ( www.r-project.org ) commands are

```
pick <- matrix(c(8,13,12,9), nrow=2)
fisher.test(pick)
```

The result is

```
> fisher.test(pick)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  pick
p-value = 0.3543
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1123735 1.8612878
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.4703282
```

So with $p>0.05$ there is not enough evidence to reject the $H_0$ that question order has no influence on the choice of A and B.

Comment: That's great, thanks. What about comparing the total choices of A and B? Is there a statistical test for the significance of that?

Comment: You mean, people got $n$ choices and they chose $n_A$ times A and $n_B$ times B and you wonder, whether this could have been a 50:50 choice? A binomial test would be suitable. The R function for that would be `binom.test`. If you use R, type `help(binom.test)` at the R console for details.